# JPA OneToOne and ManyToOne relationship with same entity

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm new in Java world, and JPA. I have a problem with OneToMany relationships.

So I have two entities: `UserEntity` and `ManagerEntity`.

The `Manager` is a `User` that was promoted,  so here we have `OneToOne` relationship where `manager_uuid` in `managers` table reference `uuid` in the `users` table. This relationship works fine.

Now each `Manager` has many `clients` => `UserEntity` and it is mapped by `managers` table.

The problem is that it keeps looking for `client_uuid` in the `users` table instead of `managers` and I don't know why...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
  private UUID uuid;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(
      name = "manager_uuid",
      referencedColumnName = "uuid")
  private ManagerEntity managerReference;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "client_uuid",
      referencedColumnName = "uuid")
  private ManagerEntity manager;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "managers")
public class ManagerEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
  private UUID uuid;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "managerReference")
  private UserEntity actingМanager;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager")
  private List<UserEntity> clients = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Migration:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS managers
(
    uuid            uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
    manager_uuid    uuid NOT NULL,
    client_uuid     uuid NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (manager_uuid) REFERENCES users (uuid),
    FOREIGN KEY (client_uuid) REFERENCES users (uuid)
)
```

The error:

> ERROR: column userentity0_.client_uuid does not exist

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's working as expected. The client_uuid is something which needs to be in user table. As one manager will be having multiple clients, you can't insert multiple client_uuid in manager table single field. But when it comes the other way around than one user will be having only one manager. So they can store the manager_uuid easily.

Comment: @DeepakKumar I don't think you get the idea... Basically, usually, you would have 3  tables: `users`, `managers` and `manager_users`. But because `User` and `Manager`  are the same I use 2 tables. So for multiplay users assigned to the manager, I  would have multiplay records and date when it was assigned. So your answer is not correct for my use case.

Comment: I think you should consider using ManyToMany relation based on your above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working as expected. The client_uuid is something which needs to be in user table. As one manager will be having multiple clients, you can't insert multiple client_uuid in manager table single field. But when it comes the other way around than one user will be having only one manager. So they can store the manager_uuid easily.

You can try make your code like below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS managers
(
    uuid            uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
    manager_uuid    uuid NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (manager_uuid) REFERENCES users (uuid)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users 
(
    uuid            uuid DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() PRIMARY KEY,
    client_uuid     uuid NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (client_uuid) REFERENCES managers(uuid)
)
```